# Most power efficient way to determine when sensor is worn

Tags: movesense

I'm working with Movesense 2.0.0 on a HR+ sensor and I have to minimize the power consumption when device is not worn.
I can't turn it completely off since I need it to keep the correct time so, to reduce the battery usage, when I don't receive a HR notification for a certain amount of time I unsubscribe from all sensors.

What's the most power efficient way to determine when device is worn again? I was thinking about subscribing to accelerometer (as I understand it is the sensor with the lowest power consuption) and when I detect movement I resubscribe to HR and check for incoming data.
Is it a valid approach?

I also noticed that when device isn't worn but still connected to the strap I sometimes receive incorrect HR notifications, like the strap is acting as an antenna for electromagnetic noise. Is there a way to detect when the device is in that status except for looking at HR data to see if they make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague in what you mean by "wear a sensor" (I'm assuming you mean HR-strap on chest). In that case if you look at the [power consumption documentation](https://movesense.com/docs/system/power_consumption/#movesense-sensor-power-consumption-measurements) (see the PowerOff measurements compared to no-wakeup) you'll notice that

- HR wakeup (*/System/States/2* (=Connector)) is ~0.2 uA
- Movement wakeup (*/System/States/0* (=Movement)) is ~4 uA

All other measurements are much higher starting from 10 uA for Acc @ 13 Hz.

So the easiest and lowest power determination is to *SUBSCRIBE* the */System/States/2*.

If you base your firmware on version >=2.1 and you measure HR or ECG you also get updates during measurement when the connection is lost (so called Leads-Off detection), so this should help to filter out the spurious HR detections. For firmware 2.0 and earlier you get Connector state 2 (*=Unknown*) when measuring.

**Note**: the leads on detection (*/System/State/2* when no HR measurement is ongoing) is very sensitive and can give "connected" state when the HR-strap is sweaty.

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*